# Problems with instantiating of HttpServletRequest with Mockito

Tags: java, testing, mockito

The following line fails with an exception:

```
HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method 
that is not native or abstract in class file 
javax/servlet/http/Cookie
```

Has anyone faced this problem?

UPD
Solution was found [here](http://www.goodercode.com/wp/absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-or-abstract/).

Comment: workaround: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html?

Answer (score 3):

You should add implementation of Servlet API to your test/runtime classpath. I would suggest to use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Actually, adding javax.servlet-api helps. Thanks anyway.